# Some application unable run in Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: 16.04

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I've installed pencil prototype and VMWare 12. But when I started to run the applications it shows the icon at the launcher and it blinking but it also disappear in short the application didn't run. Please help me guys. Thanks. :)